# UITableView that links Cell to UIWebView NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios4

My question seems simple enough and yet I have not been able to find an example to follow.
I have a UITableView with a list of courses that I want to link to their respective URLs.
There are 21 courses in the list and when the user scrolls the list, they select a course that then should link them to the web page (with a "back" button to return to the list).

I've found examples to link the URL directly from a button but not from a UITableView list.
How can you link the Cell in the TableView list to the NSURL Request to then load the web page?

Anyone with an answer or a link to a tutorial, would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the delegate methods for UITableView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In your case you probably want to push another viewcontroller with a webview when the user taps a cell so you can allow the user to go back to the uitableview when he/she is done.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Make an data object called Link with two instance variables, the URLRequest object and a string that you want for your table cell to display.

When you set up your 21 objects, make 21 Link objects and store them in an array.

In your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you will setup your row with the linkInsance.cellName value.
In your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you will get the linkInstance.URLRequest and execute it.

You will get the link instances by getting an object by index in the array with the indexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard "Navigation based application" template so that you've got a navigation controller in place.  By default it is set up to use a table view controller as its root view controller, so it's a good starting point for you.

Now create a custom view controller subclass that embeds a `UIWebView`.  Remember to create an IBOutlet for the webview and hook it up in Interface Builder.  While you are in Interface Builder, select the main view and tell it you want a navigation bar at the top.  Give your view controller an `NSURL` property too.  In the `loadView` method for this class, tell the `UIWebView` to load that URL.

Now go back to the table view controller's delegate.  In the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, create an autoreleased instance of your custom view controller.  Assign the appropriate URL to the `NSURL` property that you just set up, then push it onto the navigation stack with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:isAnimated:]`.